# Mapping c++ char*** memory to DataTable or DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, c++, datagridview, datatable, bigdata

I've been working on a program which displays a DataTable in a DataGridView in my C# frontend application. C++ is much faster at processing string comparisons however so I'm working on a solution which requires both to work with 1 DataTable basically.

My C++ code is basically a DLL with functions for string comparison. I could in theory house the data in a Vector> type of array, and I actually have a char*** myArray which has all of the pointers for each string.

My question is basically this: What is the fastest way I can display a large matrix of data which is housed in C++ memory? If I could somehow create a DataTable, or bind my DataGridView to the memory locations in myArray*** this would be phenomenal.

I've tried a few things thus far as an attempt of speeding the whole thing up, and the best I've come up with right now is this: C++ loads the data and as C++ makes changes it saves them to a .csv. The .csv is mapped in C# to a DataTable using ADO Jet 4.0. This works fairly well, it takes a couple of minutes to load the full data when 150k+ rows with 50 columns into C++, but it only takes around 20seconds to re-export to the .csv. C# loads this very quickly since it's using the ADO, however, as I make changes in C++, C# doesn't display this until the entire set of changes are made. Sometimes the changes made can take a couple of minutes so I'm stuck with presenting a progress bar over and over.

I also tried doing this with SQL which worked a little faster overall but not much. The other main reason I'm avoiding this is because the software will be run on machines where they do not always have an accessible SQL DB.

I've also tried marshalling and actually got it so that I could pass the entire DataTable from C# to C++, but this took something like 20minutes to pass from C# to C++ and load into C++. That process could've been improved, but just the marshaling of the entire DataTable took long enough this wasn't a decent approach in my mind.

So again, I'm thinking the data is already in memory created by C++, so if I could simply marshal a starting address from myArray*** to C# and have it update the DataTable accordingly that seems to be the best approach I can think of, but I'm curious, what do YOU think is the best approach?

Comment: I'm doing nGram comparisons so it's not as simple as comparing 1 string to another in full. I'm comparing every combination of 3characters for example when doing tri-gram.C# can't even process the for loops as fast as C++ to my knowledge.

Comment: The best solution I've come up with is listed which is to map C#'s DataTable as ADO via the .csv which c++ will update. This however has several downfalls like the dataGridView not updating until C++ is done processing and re-exports the new .csv.

Comment: When I'm in C++ though I'm already changing the memory address values for these strings. If I could map a DataTable to the memory locations in C# it would automatically update as C++ makes changes, and I would never have to load the .csv into C#.